# Parameters in Javascript using jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to pass a parameter from php into my javascript function inside html. Is this at all possible? This is what I've got so far, but it seems to crash once it hits the condition:

```
$str="<input type='submit' value='-' onclick='Call(".$row['field1'].");'/>";
```

I hope that I won't have to find a work around for this.

Thanks.

EDIT:
This is the function that I'm trying to call

```
function Call(stuff)
    {
    alert(stuff);
    $.get('reports.php',
    {'param':'section', 'text':stuff},
    function(returned_data)
    {
    alert(returned_data);
    });
    //alert('end');
    }
```

And this is the function that I'm populating a table with.

```
function PopTable()
    {
        alert('end');
        document.getElementById('table').innerHTML = 'Loading...';
        $.get('reports.php',
        {'param':'getstuff'},
        function(returned_data)
        {
            document.getElementById('table').innerHTML = returned_data; // Clear the select
        });
        alert('end');
    }
```

This is the php that I'm sending back population the table:

```
$str.= '<tr>';
$str.='<td  bgcolor="#ffffff">' . $row['stuff'] .'</td>';
$str.='<td><input type='submit' value='-' onclick="Call('$row['stuff']');"/></td>';
$str.='</tr>';  //accumulate table
```

I can't seem to get a return value for Call(), and the alert doesn't even pop up

Comment: Its definitely possible, you'll need to post the error that you are getting though

Comment: There isn't an error, there isn't a reaction to the button press.

Comment: What is the generated html of that `<input>` element as it appears in the browser with "view source"? If onclick has javascript with a syntax error, that would explain why it's not called. I still think this is a js escaping problem.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. It was an escaping problem. I misunderstood what you mean by escaping, earlier. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$str='<input type="submit" value="-" onclick="Call(\''.$row['field1'].'\');"/>';
```

I would bet you need quotes around the value if it is a string value

For example if `$row['field1'] = 'test';` then:

Your version: `<input type='submit' value='-' onclick='Call(test);'/>` which would fail because `test` is not a valid variable

My Version `<input type="submit" value="-" onclick="Call('test');"/>` which would work becase `'test'` is a string

Comment: Actually, it works perfectly! Thanks, but would you mind explaining why you are using backslashes?

Comment: Because I used `''` to wrap my string, when I want to put a single quote (`'`) inside that string, I have to escape it.  (e.g.: `'let\'s go'` is valid while `'let's go'` is not because PHP sees it as a `'let'` string and then `s go'` which makes no sense.)

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do *is* possible, whereas it is not possible to pass a parameter from JavaScript into a PHP function.

When you say it crashes once it hits the condition, do you mean when you click on the input on the page? In that case, it's an error in your JavaScript syntax. I would try using Firebug with Firefox to track down the issue.

My first guess is there are no quotation marks inside the Call() method. So you're doing this:

```
Call(something)
```

and it should be like this:

```
Call('something')
```

Comment: This one does make sense, but I guess I don't understand my problem well enough to fix it with this solution

Comment: Try: `$str = "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"-\" onclick=\"Call('" . $row['field1'] . "');\" />";`

Comment: If you want to have literal quotes in a PHP variable, you have to escape them using a backslash. For example, `echo "Bob says "hi"";` will cause a parsing error because the string ends when it encounters the quotation mark before "hi". The proper way to echo such a phrase would be `echo "Bob says \"hi\"";`

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but I would be very careful about mixing PHP echos and javascript inline with strings because you need to escape javascript datatypes properly

In your example, `$row['field1']` is probably from a database, so it's a string, so you need to surround the value with quotes in your javascript call. *But that's not all*, because what if there's a quote in your string, or a special character like a newline which needs to be escaped in javascript? And then what about html escaping?

A better approach is to import your javascript values in one place using `json_encode()`, then use your variables from there.

E.g.:

```
<?php
$jsonrow = json_encode($row);
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jsrow = <?=htmlspecialchars($jsonrow);?>;
</script>
<?php // some time later... ?>
<input type="submit" value="-" onclick="Call(jsrow.field1);" />
```

Comment: I can't seem to get the field to pass parameters, and I don't want to escape any character because I will use it later on to query the database again. Let me update my original answer

Comment: You need to escape characters so they can be used by javascript and then expressed in html. There's no way around this requirement.  Also your updated question makes it even less clear what error or problem you are encountering...

Comment: Check it now, it should be updated. I'm not sure if I'm using the same php approach as you. This is day 4 of my web development, so I don't have a solid understanding of this just yet.